# How to transfer record ownership from one user to another in salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-platform

Salesforce1 app doesn't have an option to transfer record  from one user to another. Is there a way to customize the app providing an option to select new owner of the record using mobile SDK or lightning.

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to be looking for guidance on how to go about doing this, I'll offer a few ideas that might kick-start your efforts.

First of all, the answer to "is there a way?" is, "Yes!"

In all likelihood there are probably several ways. Some considerations.

Is this a request for one particular object? Like Account? If the pain-point is specific, like that, it will be an easier solution, as you can write your code in an object-specific manner, which would favor a straightforward one-off Visualforce page + controller.

But if this is a global request: we want to be able to change ownership for every object we use in S1 Mobile, then you're looking at more work, especially given the way Visualforce works.

Let's take a publisher action.

A Visualforce publisher action that sits on an object page needs to use the Standard Controller for that object. Meaning you need to create a new page *for every single object* that you use in S1 Mobile. Furthermore you will need some custom Apex. Here, you might come up with a way make your controller abstract enough that you might get away with only writing one Apex class.

And finally there is the question of objects that can also be assigned to a queue. This is not so hard to test for, but you would need to create logic that would enable your user to assign the record.

Given what is available today, this would be my approach: Visualforce publisher action. The creation of individual pages for each object would be a PITA, but it would offer a lot of advantages from the UX perspective.

Lightning Components will probably have some additional features to support making this kind of customization easier in the future, but the only implementation option Lightning Components is a tab in S1 Mobile. That might be a fit for an Admin UI for mass ownership changes, but not to reproduce something akin to the standard change object ownership feature that exists today.

Mobile SDK is about building customer-facing mobile apps, really. I think building a mobile app using the Mobile SDK just to do ownership changes would be overkill.

Comment: Very good clarification. Would be great to have this on the roadmap as standard feature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that mobile SDK will be of great help inside the salesforce 1 mobile app. But transferring the owner should work easily with Lightning or Visualforce+Apex.

Look into an example to edit a single record. Take an userpicker and bind it to the owner field.